# Automated Google Script Email when two cells are updated

Tags: google-apps-script

Very inexperienced with Google Scripting and trying to run a function so that when two cells within a row are updated, an email is sent off. Below is a snippet of the script - right now, it will send an email regardless of if there is text in the "amount" column. I would like the email to send only if data appears in the amount column. Thanks!

```
if (state == "approved", "denied") {
    if (amount == "") {
        var emailAddress = "email@email.com";
        var message = "Body Text."
        var subject = "Subject"
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
```

Comment: Can you increase the information for understanding your situation? I think that providing your whole script and sample spreadsheet will help users think of your solution. Of course, when you provide them, please remove your personal information from them.

Comment: This test: `if (amount == ""){` means it will send email if `amount` is empty, perhaps you mean `if (amount != ""){`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change your `if` statement check for the amount to the following:

```
if (amount != "")
```

One thing to note is that you would probably like to `trim` the amount to ignore white spaces.

You do mention when the cells are "updated" which means that the check above will pass if you already have data in the cell but it was not changed. In that case you need to find a way to store the initial values in the cells which would probably happen upon initialization of your code. After that your check will look like this:

```
if (amount != "" && amount != previousAmountValue) {
```

There is also a problem with your first check. I think it should look like something similar to this:

```
if ((state == "approved" || state == "denied") && state != previousStateValue) {
```

That would make sure that state is either `approved` OR `denied` AND it is also different than its previous value.